# How to convert simple average function in javascript to pointfree form using Ramda?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying, pointfree, ramda.js

How do I convert the following simple `average` function to pointfree form (using Ramda)?

```
var _average = function(xs) {
  return R.reduce(R.add, 0, xs) / xs.length;
};
```

I've been this for a while now, but the `R.divide` function is throwing me off since the numerator and the denominator requires evaluation first

Comment: May be worth a read https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2011-June/007266.html

Comment: Thanks for raising a great point regarding readability. And it is definitely good to remember that _" If the point-free style isn't easy to write, it's
probably also not easy to read."_ But as an exercise, how would you answer the question in case you _had_ to.

Comment: I don't honestly don't know and it looks like a headache. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`R.converge`](http://ramdajs.com/0.22.1/docs/#converge):

```
//    average :: Array Number -> Number
const average = R.converge(R.divide, [R.sum, R.length]);
```

Using [`R.lift`](http://ramdajs.com/0.22.1/docs/#lift) (which a more generally applicable function than `R.converge`):

```
//    average :: Array Number -> Number
const average = R.lift(R.divide)(R.sum, R.length);
```

Comment: Those are much cleaner, even understandable. They look pointless even to me. Nice job. :) I'm surprised that something like `R.average` doesn't already exist? But it's all quite interesting the more I look at it.

Comment: Oh yes, there is a R.mean, easiest and cleaner way. @Xotic750: Up voted.

Comment: can someone explain why lift(divide) can take functions as arguments? I understand `lift(add)(Maybe.of(5), Maybe.of(2))`

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
let xs = [5, 5];
let average = R.compose(R.apply(R.divide), R.juxt([R.sum, R.length]));
console.log(average(xs));
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/ramda/latest/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Basically, `R.juxt` maps the array values into `R.sum` and `R.length` which gives you an array with the sum of the array and the length of the array. The result is applied to `R.divide`.

Comment: Is that why `pointfree` is also known as `pointless`? Just joking, but that does look very painful to me. :)

Comment: It took me a while to figure it out but I think it's not that bad. I'm just not used to it. Infix notation doesn't help much either.

Comment: Up voted. I feel this is the perfect pointfree soln. The soln that I provided is based on what OP wrote.

Comment: Using `R.converge`/`R.lift` is cleaner, as it obviates the need for `R.apply` and `R.compose`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below one

```
var _sum = function(xs) {
  return R.reduce(R.add, 0, xs);
};

var _average = function(xs) {
  return R.divide(_sum(xs), xs.length);
};

console.log(_average([3,4,5,6]));
```

or simply

```
var _average = function(xs) {
  return R.divide(R.reduce(R.add, 0, xs), xs.length);
};

console.log(_average([3,4,5,6]));
```

Comment: These are far less painful on my head. I assume that they meet the OP's requirement as I'm not very familiar with `pointfree`?

Comment: Your `_sum` function is better written `R.reduce(R.add, 0)` – there's no need for a wrapping function. Also, you could simply use [`R.sum`](http://ramdajs.com/0.22.1/docs/#sum). ;)

Comment: Thank you very much davidchambers, for your feedback. I heard about Ramda library and point free functions only after seeing the OP's post. Just tried to grab some idea about those quickly to answer this post and gained something. My answer based on my quick understanding. just to help OP. Secondly, after seeing MinusFour's post got some clarity and after seeing your post, I feel I understood the Ramda library and point-free functions better now. I do tried R.sum, and didn't edit the post. :). Anyway, thank you again for your feedback. Up voted,

Answer (score 0):

Simpler one:

```
R.mean([1,3]) // returns 2
```